# is there a way to alter the expiration duration of nextcord interactions?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

First of all, lords of bits, please excuse me my lack of knowledge and the possible bad code that I've written. I yarn for your expertises. Lift me up from the depths of my ignorance.

I'm currently working on a discord bot using nextcord.py library. I am displaying a sort of 'menu' using nextcord.ui.View, buttons & embeds.
[image: example of the menu]

I have defined three different classes which inherit from nextcord.ui.View, one for the main window, one for settings and one for teams. Each represent a different layer of the menu. You change layers by clicking the corresponding button, under which I have written code like so:

```
class Teams(nextcord.ui.View):
    @nextcord.ui.button(label='Main window', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def main_window(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=Lobby())
    @nextcord.ui.button(label='Settings', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def settings(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=Settings())
```

I am using interaction.response.edit_message(view=NewView()) to point to a new layer of the menu.

**My *understanding* of the problem is that the interaction expires after being idle for 3 minutes(?) after which I can no longer interact with the menu.
However, if I keep interacting with the menu by means of clicking the buttons, the interaction does not expire.**

So, my question is, like the title says, is there a way to extend the expiration time or possibly completely remove it? A way that does not involve me clicking the buttons :,)

I have read through the documents and I've tried numerous different search words, but I have not found a satisfying solution.

My current work-around is to use a queue which needs to reach a certain capacity before you can call the menu. So, when you finally do call the menu, you are more likely to use it, instead of idling.

I also tried completely ignoring the problem, but these solutions do not fully satisfy me.
I'm kinda new to programming and this is my first post, please excuse any shortcomings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class Teams, you should make a **init** method. Then use the super() function to make the timeout = None.

```py
class Teams(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    """All Buttons you create in here will have no timeout"""
```